# Parsing Values To Shell Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a simple bash script for a command so i can make it reusable for me the command has been taken from another post to convert videos with ffmpeg then upload.

Here is what i have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=$1
EXT=$2
BUCKET=$3
find "$MOVIES" -name "*.$EXT" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "${0%%.mov}.mp4" && s3cmd put "${0%%.mov}.mp4" "$BUCKET""$(basename "${0%%.mov}.mp4")"' {} \;
exit;
```

I am having issues with the third var if i run it like this.

```
sh batch.sh ~/Documents/screengrabs/ mov s3://bucket/
```

I am getting a error it encodes properly.

```
ERROR: Parameter problem: Destination must be S3Uri. Got: file://49A22352-9F41-48B9-BF97-610CBF699025-630-0000055828D0D55F.mp4
```

This means it is not parsing the $3 parameter $BUCKET properly.

Any help this is my first bash script attempt.

Thanks

Update still not working

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES="$1"
EXT="$2"
BUCKET="$3"

find "$MOVIES" -name "*.${EXT}" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "${0%%.mov}.mp4" && s3cmd put "${0%%.mov}.mp4" "${BUCKET}/sam.mp4"' {} \;

exit;
```

WORKING

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=$1
EXT=$2
export BUCKET=$3
find "$MOVIES" -name "*.$EXT" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "${0%%.mov}.mp4" && s3cmd put "${0%%.mov}.mp4" "$BUCKET""$(basename "${0%%.mov}.mp4")"' {} \;
exit;
```

Comment: I think using variables MOVIES,EXT,BUCKET like "*.${EXT}", "${BUCKET}" will work instead of $BUCKET,$EXT.

Comment: Still no luck if i hard code s3://bucket/ instead on the ${BUCKET} option it works

Comment: The command line arguments should be in quotes too like this:
BUCKET="$3"

Comment: Quoting a single parameter expansion on the RHS of an assignment is unnecessary

Comment: What does `echo "$BUCKET"` output if you put it just before the `find` command?

Comment: I have updated my answer still not working tho same error could it be something to do with the $0 all options before seems to be working

Comment: Another issue is that `$BUCKET`, being a shell variable, is not inherited by the `find` command and thus not available in the the `sh` process spawned by `find`. (Since the command to `sh` is in single quotes, it gets the literal text `$BUCKET` and tries to expand it, but it is not defined in that shell).

Comment: if i echo "${BUCKET}"; before find it echos out the right command s3://bucket/

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? You are only using `find` for its ability to search recursively from a base directory, so it will be easier to use a simple for loop to do the same. `bash` 4 allows something like `for f in $MOVIES/**/*.$EXT; do ... ;done` (ignoring proper quoting for simplicity).

Comment: This looks like a variable scope problem to me. `$BUCKET` isn't export and so isn't likely to be present in the sh script run by `find` (and since the script given to `sh` is single quoted the variable isn't expanded before being passed to `sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$0` is the name of the *script* that is executed (in this case a temporary file created by `sh` from the argument to `-c`), not the first argument to the resulting script. Note that the error message does not mention a file with `sam` in the name, so it is being generated by the `${0%%.mov}.mp4` argument to `s3cmd`, not the one that uses `$BUCKET`.   Replace it with `$1`. Also, you need to export `BUCKET` so that the shell started by `find` has access to it. (The literal string `$BUCKET`, not its value, is passed to `sh` via its `-c` option because the string is rightly single-quoted.)

(UPDATE: as Etan pointed out, `$0` is correct.)

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=$1
EXT=$2
export BUCKET=$3
find "$MOVIES" -name "*.$EXT" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "${1%%.mov}.mp4" && s3cmd put "${0%%.mov}.mp4" "$BUCKET""$(basename "${0%%.mov}.mp4")"' {} \;
exit;
```

In `bash` 4, however, I would just write

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=$1
EXT=$2
BUCKET=$3

shopt -s globstar
for movie in "$MOVIES"/**/*."$EXT"; do
    mp4movie=${movie%%.mov}.mp4
    ffmpeg -i "$movie" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "$mp4movie" &&
      s3cmd put "$mp4movie" "$BUCKET/$mp4movie"
done
```

This is much easier to get right than trying to cram a small script into a single string for `sh -c`.

---

Manual recursive search with `bash` 3.2:

```
process_file () {
    movie=$1
    mp4movie=${movie%%.mov}.mp4
    ffmpeg -i "$movie" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a libfaac -movflags faststart "$mp4movie" &&
      s3cmd put "$mp4movie" "$BUCKET/$mp4movie"
}

process_directory () {
    dir=$1
    for name in "$dir"/*; do
        if [[ -d "$name" ]]; then
            process_directory "$name"
        elif [[ -f $name && $name = *.$EXT ]]; then 
            process_file "$name"
        fi
    done
}

MOVIES=$1
EXT=$2
BUCKET=$3
process_directory "$MOVIES"
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner tried to get this to work but i just get this error /Users/user/Documents/screengrabs//**/*.mov: No such file or directory sorry i have no knowledge of bash scripts going to watch some tutorials now

Comment: When using `-c` the first non-option argument to `sh` is set to `$0`. In normal usage that is the script name but not with an explicit set of non-script non-option arguments. `sh -c 'echo "\$0:$0=$@"' foo bar baz` outputs `$0:foo=bar baz`.

Comment: Thanks, Etan. I should have double-checked that. I would edit my answer, but in light of the odd `file:` URL, I'm not sure what edit to make.

Comment: @user1503606 That error implies you are using `bash` 3.2 (and the directory implies you are using Mac OS X, whose default `bash` is indeed 3.2), so `globstar` is unavailable unless you install `bash` 4 yourself.

Comment: @chepner i have updated the answer to show what did work the export seemed to do the trick i have no idea why going to do some research while my videos upload.

Comment: When `BUCKET` is undefined (because it wasn't exported), it seems `s3cmd` turns the resulting bare file name into a `file:` URL before  reporting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner's answer about using a "native" shell script is a good one. That being said, and as I just posted in a comment on the OP, I believe the issue here is simply a variable scope issue.

If you edit the script to use `"$1"` instead of `"$BUCKET"` in the script passed to `sh -c` and add `"$BUCKET"` between the `{}` and `\;` I believe the script will work (though I haven't fully evaluated the script in other respects).